# 'Future<Uint8List?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uint8List'

Tags: flutter

I have the below code that is querying artwork from https://pub.dev/packages/on_audio_query
It is able to get the artwork in **Future<Uint8List?>** formart. How can I convert that to **Uint8List**?

```
  Future<Uint8List?> getArtWork(id)async{
    return await _audioQuery.queryArtwork(id,ArtworkType.AUDIO);
  }

Uint8List uint8List =  getArtWork(metadata.id.toString())
```

Comment: Add `await` keyword before `getArtWork`

Answer (score 2):

use await to get the Uint8List?

```
Uint8List? uint8List =  await getArtWork(metadata.id.toString())
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `getArtWork` can return null and `uint8List` variable doesnt accept nullable data.

You can make it nullable

```dart
youMethod() async{
   Uint8List? uint8List =  await getArtWork(metadata.id.toString());
}
```

Comment: I am getting **type 'Future<Uint8List?>' is not a subtype of type 'Uint8List?' in type cast**

Comment: You need to use async method